# Getting java runtime enviroment not found error while running .exe file produced bt jar2exe software

Tags: java, runtime

I am getting the following message immediately after trying to run the executable file.

> Java Runtime Environment not found.

I have installed jdk and jre and already set the path for both and able to run any class file with command prompt.
Unfortunately, i am not using Netbeans or Eclipse.
**please someone help**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found jar2exe website support that include install 32 bit jre for 32 bit OS and 64 bit jre for 64 bit OS. The best solution is reinstall correct version of Java and choose offline installer (since online installer mostly install 32 bit before, but I don't sure is smart enough to detect 32 bit or 64bit now).
(I'm sorry that I don't gain enough reputation to post on comments)

Answer (score 0):

You need an appropriate jre installed that is the same with your Jar2Exe (on step 6 during Exe creation). If you're check "Create 64 bits executive" on those step you'll need 64 bit jre, but if you unchecked it then you need 32 bit jre.